# How to avoid printing Python warnings

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection

I am writing a bash script that is running some commands; here's an excerpt:

```bsh
echo -en "\nStage 2: Launching Bot\e[1;0m\n"
python main.py
```

The output of `python main.py` contains a lot of multi-line warnings at the beginning. How do I only show the lines of output that start with "[Bot]" (or is there a way to not output those warnings)?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please add a (possibly anonymized, if sensitive data may be exposed) example of the raw output that the `python` call currently generates, and an indication which lines should be removed. Concerning your question in parentheses - without knowing what `main.py` looks like, it is impossible to tell. Also please indicate what you tried and where you failed, so that contributors don't propose solutions you already know won't work.

Comment: @AdminBee -- Just solved my own issue, so I'm posting an answer.

Comment: Fix the python warnings properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To suppress warnings, I used the python `warnings` module.

```py
# this should be at the very top of the file
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

# the rest of the code, including all other import statements, goes here
```

Now, it only prints out errors and whatever I want it to output.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is actually about ignoring Python warnings (which are usually there for a reason), reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html) actually yields the nice and concise `python - Wignore` which avoids having to modify (potentially third-party) code.